# Powershell Get-Acl for HKLM:\SECURITY Issues

Tags: powershell

I am a novice at PowerShell and had a question regarding a script I am working on.

```
"$env:computername" | Out-File -FilePath C:\CS\"$env:computername"_RegACL.txt 
Get-Acl HKLM:\SOFTWARE | Format-List | Out-File -FilePath C:\CS\"$env:computername"_RegACL.txt -Append
Get-Acl HKLM:\SYSTEM | Format-List | Out-File -FilePath C:\CS\"$env:computername"_RegACL.txt -Append
Get-Acl HKLM:\SECURITY | Format-List | Out-File -FilePath C:\CS\"$env:computername"_RegACL.txt -Append
```

The script runs all the way through, but will not record the HKLM:\SECURITY information. I have been elevating and have appropriate permissions. I researched some potential fixes, but came up with limited and unhelpful info.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `"C:\CS\$($env:computername)_RegACL.txt"` for the output file path.

Comment: The script does write to the file for the SOFTWARE and SYSTEM, but SEUCRITY is missing, even when I run that line individually.

Answer (score -1):

The administrator does not have read permissions, only special permissions, to pull the permissions form HKLM:\SECURITY, manually check regedit and this will make sense